# How to install jenkins plugin by java program

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I want to install jenkins plugin programmatically using java. can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You can access Jenkins remotely using the [remote api](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) .
This can be used to install plugins as well, look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/basmussen/8182784) and for example:

```
curl -X POST -d '<jenkins><install plugin="git@2.0" /></jenkins>' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins
```

will install the git plugin.
So by using some HTTP library in Java you can do this from Java as well, posting HTTP requests to the remote api and installing plugins.

Comment: Using remote api,i dint find any way like how to give the line "<jenkins><install plugin="git@2.0"/></jenkins> in java .  Any one please help me

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily